# What is the best setup to stub functionality when testing node.js apps?

Tags: testing, node.js, mocking, stub, vows

I'm new to Node.js and in general new to testing frameworks / methods in Javascript.  So far I'm thinking of giving [vows](http://vowsjs.org/) a try.

Specifically, I'd like to be able to stub / mock my data sources.  I'm considering two situations:

1. Stub out the whole module
2. Stub out just a single function when for whatever reason stubbing the whole module doesn't work.

Any suggestions or examples for the approach you found cleanest and simplest to use?

Comment: Depends on the architecture. You should have a datasource module which you can stub out. There are libraries that make emulating certain data sources easier (I know theres a mocking library for couchdb). Personally I dont mock out data source, I just write integration tests

Comment: Raynos, thanks for the comment.  In our case, we definitely want to stub out at least some tests.  I am asking for advice specifically on stubbing out node.js modules and/or functions. Latter has quite a bit of examples on the web, I'd love some thoughts on best practices..

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have been enjoying using Mocha + Chai + Sinon as my stack.  It is a headache to set up at first (sinon especially..), but once you get it up, everything feels so natural.

Sinon is a very powerful library that allows you to fake http requests or even the server.  You get a choice between stubs/spies/and mocks.  About the only thing I have found that it doesn't do is dom-based event mocking..

If I were you, I would load up the modules as they are and stub/spy on their behavior with Sinon.  I know some people have attempted to load up entire mock modules, but I personally think that is too intrusive to the code you're testing.